# Scoping Issue with React when calling a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having some difficulty in getting scope maintained when calling a function within a function when using React,  I have created an onChange function, that calls another function called buildBookingQuery

```
handlePerPageChange = (data) => {
    const elementsIndex = this.state.filters.findIndex(element => element.id == 1)
    let newArray = [...this.state.filters]
    newArray[elementsIndex] = {...newArray[elementsIndex], perPage: parseInt(data.target.value)}
    this.setState({
        filters: newArray
    })
    console.log(this.state.filters[0])
    console.log(newArray)

    let query = this.buildBookingQuery() => This is the problem function
    console.log(query)
}
```

my buildBookingQuery Function

```
buildBookingQuery (){
    let page = 1
    let orderby = this.state.filters[0].orderby.split(" ")
    let from = this.state.filters[0].fromDate
    let to = this.state.filters[0].toDate
    let reservedFrom = this.state.filters[0].reservedFromDate
    let reservedTo = this.state.filters[0].reservedToDate

    console.log("Build Booking Query:", from) => getting undefined

    // rest of code removed for sake of brevity 
    return someValue 
}
```

from researching I have added the bind event to the constructor

`this.buildBookingQuery = this.buildBookingQuery.bind(this);`

but to no avail.

your help is appreciated

Comment: use arrow function

Answer (score 0):

change your `buildBookingQuery` function to arrow function and also remove binding also.

Comment: buildBookingQuery = () => { let from = this.state.filters[0].fromDate  console.log("Build Booking Query:", from); } done but still getting undefined

Comment: change this.buildBookingQuery() to buildBookingQuery()

Comment: is it help you?

Comment: when I remove "this" I am getting buildBookingQuery is not defined

Comment: thanks for the help Dishant Desai but unfortunately I dont think I can ,  I shall keep hunting google

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219195/discussion-between-dishant-desai-and-dbjoe).

Answer (score 0):

my issue was myself this line of code:

this.state.filters[0].fromDate

should have been:

this.state.filters[0].startDate

thank for all your help, long day and tired eyes!